# how to start new independent process from java

Tags: java, linux, windows, process

I am working on a program written in Java which should launch a new external process that is independent of the parent process. Currently I'm using `ProcessBuilder` and `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(somecmd)` but it always depends on parent process.

The program must run under Windows and Linux. I've read [How to run a shell script from Java and have it continue running after JVM shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154189/how-to-run-a-shell-script-from-java-and-have-it-continue-running-after-jvm-shutd), but it doesn't solve my problem as it only works under Linux.

The goal is that the parent process can die but the child processes continues.

Comment: The duplicate actually answers your question, but I had to look twice to notice that.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs thanks for quick answer, but i my problem is litter bit different
i want launches a new process in both environment linux as well as in windows 
i have a file called xyz.sh in linux system and xyz.cmd in window system, need to run different process .

Comment: nohup command works in linux system only, i want generic solution.
any configurations change in process builder ..

Comment: you can check the running operating system by System.getProperty and then issue the matching commands for linux and windows. In windows its `start` iirc. (this comment should be an answer, ping me after this question was reopened)

Comment: @AngeloFuchs yes we can use "start" for windows  but i don't want to use any cmd which is system (operating system ) dependent. i want to use java api for this task .
i am checking processbuilder , is any configuration setting is required to for run independent process ?
.

Comment: i solved above problem by using processbuilder.redirectOutput("file name"'). function but this is available jdk 1.7 onward.